Question regarding the name of the Father
I currently came across some question regarding the name of the Father in the Trinity, God the creator. I have seen that a lot of people use the tetragrammaton YHWH especially in the case of Judaism, but I also have come across Jehovah and I have others claim the name of the father to be Yahweh.
I understand that this is more Judaism focused but I think it deeply should concern us Christians partially because I have come across people all over the internet using the name of the Father to make really outlandish, blasphemous and heretical claims as to the origins of Christianity and Judaism and I personally feel very strongly about it because it not only changes how people look at Christianity and Judaism as a faith but also because it is outright disrespectful for the Abrahamic faiths in general.
And so because I want clarity on this subject I want to know if as a Christian, one should attribute the name of the Father as Jehovah or Yahweh? Because the tetragrammaton יהוה keeps the vowels hidden, but again I think it matters because people are associating different agendas to the name of the Father.
Edit: For added context as to what the claims that had been made by people is when I came across people and scholars saying that Yahweh was an ancient Canaanite God among a pantheon of gods and even saying he had a goddess wife and in this case I definitely think it matters because what in the world is happening here. People are trying to discredit the authenticity of the Abrahamic faith.
I personally think this is blasphemous and actually an attack at someone's faith and believe.

the pronunciation of the yhwh was lost bec the Jews gave the vowells of adonai to yhwh to censor it out of reverence. It is a misconception as some claim that name means "I am", as some false translate. see this answer for some detail https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53387/does-jesuss-name-lose-authority-in-other-languages-catholic/53394#53394

@Michael16 I have read your answer and must I say I whole heartedly agree and I never seemed to have a problem before I came across people and scholars saying that Yahweh was an ancient Canaanite God among a pantheon of gods and even saying he had a goddess wife and in this case I definitely think it matters because what in the world is happening here. People are trying to discredit the authenticity of the Abrahamic faith.

You should've explicitly formed that question on that topic, bec just reading about the "agenda" seemed to be implying about sacred name cults. I have also heard about those fringe claims among some atheists, but have not seen any response or havent from good popular level sources.

@Michael16 If you google anything about it, it will lead you straight to evidences of inscriptions on objects from ancient Canaanite sites and I shall say it is very misleading. And such agendas are being spewed like nothing all over Tiktok and YouTube following weird beliefs like "Annunakis", spirituality trope. It is just not based on anything concrete but I feel like it has influence on people.

I use duckduckgo, the biblearchaelogy articles maybe useful and too technical perhaps, though I am also interested to read the refutation by scholars, and not just simple apologetics sites. https://biblearchaeology.org/research/exodus-from-egypt/3233-the-name-yahweh-in-egyptian-hieroglyphic-texts

@Michael16 I don't know if you know you Michael Heiss is but He has a sort of refutation regarding the topic. He is the only scholar I know that has dealt with this specific topic.

Consider English Translation of “JESUS” | Collins Portuguese-English Dictionary:



Language
Spelling




American English
Jesus  /dˈʒizəs/


Arabic
ﻲَﺳُﻮﻋ


Brazilian Portuguese
Jesus


Chinese
耶稣


Croatian
Isus


Czech
Ježíš


Danish
Jesus


Dutch
Jezus


European Spanish
Jesús


Finnish
Jeesus


French
Jésus


German
Jesus


Greek
Ιησούς


Italian
Gesù


Japanese
イエス


Korean
예수


Norwegian
Jesus


Polish
Jezus


European Portuguese
Jesus


Romanian
Iisus


Russian
Иисус


Latin American Spanish
Jesús


Swedish
Jesus


Thai
พระเยซูคริสต์


Turkish
İsa


Ukrainian
Ісус


Vietnamese
chúa Giê-su



There are of course hundreds more languages to consider.
And the spellings themselves aren't simply how an English speaker would pronounce them (e.g. Spanish "Jesús" is pronounced "Hay ZOOSE".
And it's quite likely that Jesus's mother pronounced the name as  ישוע (Yeshua), which in English is spelled "Joshua".
Acts 4:12 tells us:

(KJV) Neither is there salvation in any other: for there is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved.
(NLT) There is salvation in no one else! God has given no other name under heaven by which we must be saved.”

Does it really matter that almost everyone pronounces Jesus's name differently than his mother did?
If it does, then effectively no one has ever been saved, certainly not any English speaker.
Obviously it isn't the pronunciation that counts, it's one's mental association with the name that's important.
There's no reason it shouldn't be the same when pronouncing "YHWH" as "Yahweh", or "Jehova", or "Yahooh", or "God", or … .

A quote from Shakespeare “a rose by any other name would smell as sweet” has important meaning which applies to the everyday life of all humans.  This quote suggest that a name is just a label to distinguish one thing from another.  Humans understand their world by categorizing similar things into groups and labeling them.  The name really has no worth nor does the label have any meaning.  The importance of a person or thing is the way it is; not because of what it is called.
— "A Rose, by any other name, would Smell as Sweet"


Plus one for "Yahooh"!

Thank you for the answer. You are definitely right and I agree!

I wholeheartedly agree and gave an upvote as well. It doesn't matter how you pronounce God's name, as long as you do so in respect and awe of his qualities. I've seen many opposing the pronunciation of "Jehovah" because it seems to cause allergic reactions as they associate the name directly with what they think is a heretic religious group. As noted in the response above, you shouldn't say "Jesus" either then, as it is equally as bad, especially if you have trinitarian belief, and think he is God Almighty.

Very comprehensive, thanks Ray.
